# Where to find the Linux changelog of minor versions

Tags: linux, kernel

I know, that there are several websites, that will list the changelog of kernel versions (e.g. what is new in 4.17) ([KernelNewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions), [heise.de](https://www.heise.de/thema/Kernel_Log)), but where do I find information about a minor change (e.g. 4.17.1 -> 4.17.2)?

(I try to hunt a bug, that appears in a very old kernel version, but not in a slightly newer one, so I'm interested in the changes, but I do not want to crawl the whole Git log.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The changelogs are on [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/).

The URLs have a predictable pattern. The current kernel change log is at:
https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.17.8

So, to read the changes from 4.17.1, you would go to:
https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.17.2