# Best method for searching linux kernel changelog from 4.18.0 to 4.20.16

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

My question is similar to this question:

[Where to find the Linux changelog of minor versions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457345/where-to-find-the-linux-changelog-of-minor-versions)

But I would like to search all changelogs from 4.18.0 to 4.20.16 for any reference to a specific word, such as sama5d3, mmc0, or other term.

I can search the individual changelogs but didn't see a way to search a set at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search across multiple changelogs, I would recommend using the git repository. For stable releases, clone the stable tree:

```
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git linux-stable
```

This will take a little while, it involves downloading 2 GiB of data. If you don’t need all the history you could use a shallow clone instead:

```
git clone --shallow-since=v4.18 --no-single-branch https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git linux-stable
```

(You need `--no-single-branch` if you want to compare different major releases since each stream of stable releases is its own branch starting from a major release.)

Then in `linux-stable`, you can use `git log` to view logs, filtering with the various options, *e.g.*

```
git log --grep=sama5d3 v4.18..v4.20.16
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` easily searches multiple files. If a match is found, by default, the file name of each match is printed together with the matched token. Hence, fetch the logs of interest, for example:

```
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.20.7
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.20.8
...

grep mmc0 ChangeLog-4.20*
```

Comment: That is a lot of wget steps, but I could set up a script to automate the boundaries of the particular search of interest...

Comment: `rsync -zarv --include="*/" --include="ChangeLog*" --exclude="*" -m 'rsync://rsync.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/' .` worked for me for downloading all changelog files.